# NServiceBus and Ninject - access to an NSB message property

Tags: ninject, nservicebus, multi-tenant

We're using NServiceBus and Ninject for a multi-tenant SaaS application.

When the user is accessing our web site or API we can determine which account the user is connected to by examining the host name of the HttpContext Request object, retrieving various settings about the account (one of which is the database we should connect to) and the rest of the request is connected to the correct database (various other checks take place).

In our NSB Windows service we don't have that concept of a shared context by which we can determine the host database to connect to so we've created a property on our base command classes that stores the account/database who created the command/message.

When the message handler is constructed for the incoming message, one of the dependencies is a repository that takes the name of the database it should be connecting to as an argument.

As said before, Ninject can access the correct DB in the HttpContext for web requests but for the NSB service the message itself contains the DB details which we can only access after the handler is constructed, which obviously fails as it requires an argument (which is contained within the message!) to successfully construct the repository. Chicken and egg :)

This is a long winded way of asking...

- Is there anyway to access the properties of a message during the Ninject creation cycle?
- This feels like one of those hard problems that's hard because my architecture is 'wrong', is that the case?
- I want to avoid putting a public property on a repository like "SetDatabase" as that feels like it could be easily abused/misunderstood and cause havoc with users data.
- I'd also thought about creating a repository factory, that Ninject would use but still not sure how to access the incoming message properties.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit for solution

I ended up using a hybrid approach from the answers from Udi and Eben.

I used an out going message mutator for my API messages that added the account name of the customer to the headers (from the HttpContext) of the outbound message.
Then, in the NSB Windows service I used an inbound mutator to examine the headers and extract the account name, as suggest by Udi.

I also created two instances of an interface that provided the connection string / account details to my repositorys as suggested by Eben. One to be used in web requests and one ThreadStatic type to be set by the incoming mutator and then Ninject bound to be used for repo instantiation for NSB.

I can't mark both as correct , sorry Eben!:)

Comment: I have a similar architecture, and similar problem. How did you configure your container registrations to pick up the tenant from the inbound message mutator? Could you share some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at using the unit of work or message mutator hooks for doing that kind of work. More info here:

http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/860275-unit-of-work-in-nservicebus

http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/860492-pipeline-management-using-message-mutators

I'd also recommend using headers on your messages for that kind of information rather than putting it on a base class.

Comment: Thanks Udi, are your header recommendations because the account info. is meta data about a connection?

Comment: Would a Transport Message Mutator be suitable to add the correct account name to outbound messages and the unit of work Begin() method being used to inspect the inbound messages header?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely seem to have a bit of an architecture issue.

To work around this an option may be to have something like a `ITenantProvider` that is implemented by a `HttpTenantProvider` and a `ThreadStaticTenantProvider`.  For your web site you could inject the http version into the repository and it would ask the instance for, say, `TenantProvider.DatabaseName` (or whatever you need).  For the endpoint implementation you could go with the 'thread static' implementation.  I just say thread static since you are going to be accessing the tenant provider instance from multiple threads and may need thread specific state.  But however you decide to do it is up to you :)

At the start of your message processing you could cast to the thread static version and call something along the lines of `((TheadStaticTenantProvider)TenantProvider).SetCurrentMessage(theMessage)`.  The repository will then receive the required data via the thread static tenant provider from the message.

In [Shuttle](http://shuttle.codeplex.com/) we use processing pipelines so I would create a module that plugs into the pipeline that processes received message to set the message on the tenant provider for me.  I don't know NServiceBus well enough but there may be something similar where you can hook into an event after the message is received to set this for you.

I hope I have made sense :)

Comment: Thanks, I actually use a model like that for connection strings and I don't know why I didn't think to extend that... :)

For clarification, are you proposing that every message handler would have to call a method that set the current message to be able to access the host name? Presumably in a base class or some such?